Migrating from NGINX-Ingress to Kubernetes Gateway API: Support for mTLS and Certificate Pinning
We are planning to migrate the NGINX Ingress Controller on our GKE clusters to the new Kubernetes Gateway API. However, we are facing challenges finding a Kubernetes Gateway API implementation that supports both mutual TLS (mTLS) and certificate pinning.
I came across this blog post that demonstrates how to implement mTLS and certificate pinning using the Istio Ingress Gateway: https://medium.com/microsoftazure/certificate-pinning-for-mtls-authentication-at-the-istio-ingress-gateway-978ed31699ab. I also noted that Istio supports mTLS for their Gateway API implementation as described in their documentation: https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress/#configure-a-mutual-tls-ingress-gateway.
My question is: Does Istio's Gateway API implementation also support certificate pinning? If not, is there a way to configure it to forward the client certificate to the backend, so we can apply pinning at the backend (which is our current setup)?
these are our current nginx ingress annotations for forwarding the certificate, we would need to replace it with equivalent Istio config code:
nginx ingress config for forwarding client cert to backend
Any insights or experiences with implementing this on Istio Gateway API would be greatly appreciated!
